# ReactJS - How to have a string with multiple colors for each characters

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs and Javascript and I'm writing a website with `create-react-app`.
I want to have the title of my homepage to show in different color-blocks, with a cutting point decided a priori. E.g. if the cutting point is set to 9 and the length of the title returned by `String.length` is 63, each color-block will show a different color every 7 chars.

I suspect the problem I am encountering is related to JSX syntax, since the issue is not happening with the same approach with vanilla Javascript. Any elucidation on this point is much appreciated.

### Approach

I created a new functional component called `ColorText` which handles the coloring of the string. This component is called in the `render()` method of my main class `App`, and it is responsible of returning the colored version of the original string passed by the parent class.

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { GlobalStyle } from './styles/global_style.js';
import { ColorText } from './components/ColorText.js';
import morning_gif from './assets/morning3D.gif';

const TitleStyle = styled.h1`
  font-family: BethEllen;
  font-size: 30pt;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
`;

const MorningGif = styled.img`
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
`;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    message: "This is some example text, and it will be colorful as a rainbow!",
    colorBreakPoint: 9,
    colorScheme: {
      pink: 'rgb(255,180,172)',
      green: 'rgb(103,145,134)',
      blue: 'rgb(38,78,112)'
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>

        <GlobalStyle />

          <div>
            <h1>
              <TitleStyle>
                <ColorText content={this.state} />
              </TitleStyle>
            </h1>
          </div>

        <MorningGif src={morning_gif} alt="Loading the coffee..." />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the `ColorText` component.

```js
export const ColorText = ({ content: { message, colorBreakPoint, colorScheme } }) => {

  const colorSpan = (message.length % colorBreakPoint) === 0 ?
                    message.length / colorBreakPoint
                  : message.length / 5;

  const colorKeys = Object.keys(colorScheme);

  let currentColor = 0;
  let colorMessage = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++){

    if ((i % colorSpan) === 0){
      currentColor++;
    }

    if (currentColor === 3){
      currentColor = 0;
      }

    colorMessage[i] = ("<span style={{ color: '"
      + colorScheme[colorKeys[currentColor]]
      + "' }}>" + message[i]
      + "</span>");
  }

  return colorMessage.join("");
}
```

The expected output is a string whose chars are enclosed by a `<span></span>` tag, with an inline attribute `style` specifying the color for each enclosed char (e.g. `<span style={{ color: 'rgba(255,180,17)' }}>H</span><span style={{ color: 'rgba(103,145,134)' }}>I</span>` etc).

### Problem

However, this is the current output:
[multicolors-string-output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8wHH.png)

The string is being rendered as a string itself, and the HTML-tagged content is not evaluated as JSX object. I tried enclosing the `ColorText` component in braces when called by `App` and the same with `return {colorMessage.join("")}` in `ColorText`, but nothing changes.
I googled several options and tried different approaches, but I guess the problem is I am not understanding JSX syntax - being new even to Javascript. Any explanation on this point is super helpful!

**NOTE**: Here is the Javascript reproduction of the ColorText component and its output https://jsfiddle.net/qz4Lxdak/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return an array with JSX elements.

```
let colorMessage = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++){

    if ((i % colorSpan) === 0){
      currentColor++;
    }

    if (currentColor === 3){
      currentColor = 0;
    }

    colorMessage[i] = (
        <span style={{ color: colorScheme[colorKeys[currentColor]].toString() }}>
            {message[i]}
        </span>
    );
  }

return colorMessage;
```